# How to insert this array to mysql using loop?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How to insert this array [$obj] to mysql using loop?

```
Array
(
    [apple] => Array
        (
            [0] => fruit
            [1] => 15
        )

    [cat] => Array
        (
            [0] => animal
            [1] => 400
        )

    [pumpkin] => Array
        (
            [0] => vegetables
            [1] => 20
        )

    [orange] => Array
        (
            [0] => fruit
            [1] => 30
        )
)
```

I want to insert array [$obj] into mysql using loop like this.

```
|___id__|___ product__|_____type_____|__price__|
|   1   |     apple   |    fruit     |    15   |
|   2   |     cat     |    animal    |    400  |
|   3   |   pumpkin   |  vegetables  |    20   |
|   4   |    orange   |    fruit     |    30   |
```

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tableName (product, type, price) VALUES";
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    $sql += " ('$key', '$value[0]', $value[1]),";
}
$sql +=  substr_replace($sql,"",-1). ";";
//perform your INSERT here.
```

Be sure to replace `tableName` and `$array` by their respective names

Comment: @Strawberry, is it what you mean, or you meant it's better with prepared statement?

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond: brother you can use implode function ...first fill this in an array and then perform implode function

Comment: @Strawberry it did, i'll replace that

Comment: @user3598505 what do you mean, not working? Did you encouter a MySql error? does the php return an error?

Answer (score 0):

try this out $obj is your array

```
$finalarray = array();
foreach($obj as $main_key=>$main_value)
{
$product = $main_key;
$type = $main_value[0];
$price = $main_value[1];
$string = "('','$product','$type','$price')";
$finalarray[] = $string;

}
$final_values_array = implode(',',$finalarray);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLENAME('id','product','type','price') VALUES $final_values_array");
```

Comment: may i know what is your array name

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
$array=Array
(
    [apple] => Array
        (
            [0] => fruit
            [1] => 15
        )

    [cat] => Array
        (
            [0] => animal
            [1] => 400
        )

    [pumpkin] => Array
        (
            [0] => vegetables
            [1] => 20
        )

    [orange] => Array
        (
            [0] => fruit
            [1] => 30
        )
)
$query = "INSERT INTO tableName (product, type, price) VALUES";
$sub='';
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    $sub.="('$key', '$value[0]', $value[1]), ";
}
$sql = $query . substr_replace($sub,"",-1);
```

This is batch insert